# jQuery UI min/max date difference for calendar

Tags: jquery, date, user-interface, calendar

I am using a plugin which uses jquery UI for its calendar on a booking form and would like to display an alert, and not allow the form to be submitted if either the 2nd date is less that lets say 7 days from first date, or if it is over 30 days from first date.

so `[01.01.2012] + [02.01.2012]` would not work

but
`[01.01.2012] + [15.01.2012]` would work, any idea how I can achive this through jquery? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JmYCN/)

Basically the jist here is that you need to `Date.parse()` both dates (which brings them into milliseconds) then divide those millseconds by / 1000 (to get seconds) / 60 (to get minutes) / 1440 (to get days).

Then test to see if it's over 7 and boom you're all set!

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    var toDate = Date.parse($('#toDate').val()),
        fromDate = Date.parse($('#fromDate').val()),
        difference = toDate - fromDate;

    var days = difference / 1000 / 60 / 1440;

    if ( days < 7 ) {
        alert('Please give at least 7 days between the dates!');
        return false; // stop from submitting        
    }

    // VALID
    else {
        alert('success!');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Will give this a spin shortly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using javascipt date object.
Let's say Date1 your first date object and Date2 the second one.

```
var dateMin = new Date(Date.parse(Date1)); //you may not need to parse. 
var dateMax = new Date(Date.parse(Date1)); //new Date(Date1) may work. Not sure

dateMin.setDate(Date1.getDate() + 7);
dateMax.setDate(Date1.getDate() + 15);

if (Date2 < dateMax && Date2 > dateMin) {
    //code
} else {
    //alert
}
```

You can do the same thing for month, year, hour etc. also.