# How can i make an input date limit when you are typing or chosing the date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit in special year :
Ex: year <= 2200 when he is typing ;

```
<input type="date" max="2200-01-01" min="1900-01-01" class="form-control" id="regdate"
                   placeholder="Registration Date">
```

Sorry for bad my bad  expressions... P.S WITHOUT SUBMIT !- when you type you can type over 2200 or under 1900.

Comment: Meaning you want the year to be between those two, or you want those two years exclusively?

Comment: I think [this](http://tiffanybbrown.com/2013/10/24/date-input-in-html5-restricting-dates-and-thought-for-working-around-limitations/) will help you to sort out the issue.

Comment: between 1900 and 2200 but not when i'm submiting...

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232638/min-max-attribute-with-type-date-on-html5) and possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075967/jquery-ui-min-max-date-difference-for-calendar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it via html, but You can use js for it, example here http://fiddle.jshell.net/5Sup8/

```
$(function () {
    $('input').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val().split('-');
        console.log(val);
        if (val[0] < 1900 || val[0] > 2200) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers; include some code directly in your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation to achieve this. A simple date range validation

```
function dateCheck() {
var fDate = new Date("1900/01/01");
var lDate; = new Date("2200/01/01");
fDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("fDate").value);
lDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("lDate").value);

if(fDate <= lDate) {
    alert("true");
    return true;
}
alert("false");
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, wrap it in form tag, Make input tag required, it will work, when you try to submit above or below the max or min values, it will display the alert

```
                 <form>
          <input type="date" max="2200-01-01" min="1900-01-01" class="form-control" id="regdate"  placeholder="Registration Date" required />
               <input type="submit" />
                 </form>
```

[Check the working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z28D9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below fiddle for reference

```
<body>

<form>

  Enter a date before 1980-01-01 and after1900-01-01:
  <input type="date" name="bday" min="1901-12-31" max="1979-12-31"><br>


  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p6Vwt/2/)